# Add RAID 0 to 13.04 desktop

Tags: raid, dmraid

I have a Buffalo NAS whose network interface crapped out. I want to take the two 500 gb drives set up as RAID 0 out and put them in a 13.04 desktop so I can access the data. Any answers? Suggestions?

I also have a Windows 7 machine I could try this on. I only trust Ubuntu though.

Following your instructions I get the result:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l 

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x21e120e1 

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/sda1              63     2008124     1004031   83  Linux 
/dev/sda2         2008125    12016619     5004247+  83  Linux 
/dev/sda4        12016620   976768064   482375722+   5  Extended 
/dev/sda5        12016683    14024744     1004031   82  Linux swap / Solaris 
/dev/sda6        14024808   974984849   480480021   83  Linux 

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes 
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x00000000 

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/sdb1              63     2008124     1004031   83  Linux 
/dev/sdb2         2008125    12016619     5004247+  83  Linux 
/dev/sdb4        12016620   976768064   482375722+   5  Extended 
/dev/sdb5        12016683    14024744     1004031   82  Linux swap / Solaris 
/dev/sdb6        14024808   974984849   480480021   83  Linux 

Disk /dev/sdc: 1007 MB, 1007681536 bytes 
31 heads, 62 sectors/track, 1024 cylinders, total 1968128 sectors 
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes 
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
Disk identifier: 0x000d82ba 

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System 
/dev/sdc1   *          62     1968127      984033    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Note: The package `mdadm` is not present on the live USB Boot.

In terminal I ran: `sudo gparted` and this resulted in:

```
/dev/sda 465.76 GiB
/dev/sdb 465.76 GiB
/dev/sdc 961.00 MiB
```

Does that help?

Comment: Plug in the drives and see what they look like.  If you have the `mdadm` package installed and are lucky, it should automatically be recognized as /dev/mdxx, where xx will probably be 127, and you should be able to mount it in the gui.  If not check what `fdisk -l` shows and edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Boot the Ubuntu live CD. Once up, open a terminal and see what partitions the kernel sees.

`$ sudo fdisk -l`

Note what device the attached HDDs are named such as dev/hda or /dev/hdb and so on...

Create mount point

`$ mkdir /media/hdd1`

`$ mkdir /media/hdd2`

Mount each HDD as follows:

`$ sudo mount /dev/hda? /media/hdd1`

`$ sudo mount /dev/hda? /media/hdd2`

Note:

? is the partition number so if each HDD has multiple partitions then mount each of them accordingly.

Comment: How does this help with RAID 0?

Comment: Yes, this misses the mark on the raid, and also /dev/hd* went away many years ago.  IDE/SATA drives are treated as scsi so they show up as /dev/sd*.